# Running test by Spec and Capybara the html element can not load if I append it through request an extern javascript resource

Tags: rspec, capybara, integration-testing

Here is the Image of my project

[We have two link work fine in normal browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d4V4.png)

We can see the Sign in and  Sign up in the navbar.  I through request a extern javascript file to append them.

$.get('xxxx/extern.js')

But when I run the test by Rpec and Capybara I can not get these two link.

There is the screenshot for my test

[Missing two link in the test browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQRwj.jpg)

I try to enlarge the waiting time `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15` but not working

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: Selenium Chrome, and It also have the same problem in Selenium firefox.

Answer (score 0):

what is your firefox and chrome version and also open a console and refresh your page and see may be link are not rendering